# How to a sort a big list lazily (to escape Stack Overflow)?

Tags: flutter, algorithm, sorting, dart

I have a big list of 50k lines. Now when I try to sort it with `list.sort` it throws `Stack Overflow` error.
How to make the sorting work lazily without filling the stack?

```
List<List<dynamic>> sortData(List<List<dynamic>> data,
    {int sortItemNumber = 4}) {
  data.sort((List<dynamic> a, List<dynamic> b) {
    return compare(a[sortItemNumber], b[sortItemNumber]);
  });
  return data;
}

int compare(var itemA, var itemB) {
  if (itemA.runtimeType == String || itemB.runtimeType == String) {
    return -1;
  }
  return itemA.compareTo(itemB);
}
```

Comment: try using `insertionSort` from `collection` package https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/insertionSort.html

Comment: Are you sure returning -1 is a good idea? `compare(a,b)` returning the same as `compare(b,a)` might upset some algorithms.

Comment: You should not be encountering a stack overflow. That's probably indicative of your comparison function being broken (as pointed out by Mark Ransom) and causing the sorting algorithm to go into an infinite loop.

Comment: @MarkRansom This is testing code. I had these mixed data types so I was testing different values.
@jamesdlin I used a different sorting method which works a small list, but raised a `Stack Overflow` on a big list. So IMO the sorting method is ok.

Comment: I would not consider 50K to be exceptionally large.  I used your code to sort a `List` with 1M `int`s with no problem (generated with `var list = [for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) [i, i, i, i, i]]..shuffle();`). However, I *can* reproduce your problem if `compare` always returns -1.  So, as has been stated, your `compare` function is broken.  Remove the `return -1` code path.

Answer (score 2):

Your `compare` function always returns -1 for certain inputs.  Those inputs can't be sorted, because there's no way to know if an element comes before or after anything else - you're saying `a<b` and `b<a` are both simultaneously true.  So the sort fails.  Different sorting algorithms will fail in different ways, yours evidently generates a stack overflow probably due to infinite recursion.

Since you say this is just for testing at the moment, you could try replacing with `return 0` to indicate those items are equivalent and thus already in the proper order.  The sort will still be incorrect, but it probably won't crash any more.